# HTML file renders blank

Tags: html

I am totally confused, my HTML file renders blank. I edited something and don't remember what.
What could be the problem? Thanks in advance!

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="canonical" href="none">
<title>akalas.de</title>
<style>* { box-sizing: border-box; } a { color: rgb(122, 122, 184); text-decoration: underline; transition: color .1s ease-ou>
</head>
<body style="color: rgb(217, 230, 242); background-color: rgb(13, 25, 38); font-family: Consolas, monospace; margin: 0; paddi>
<div style="display: flex; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; align-items: center; justify-content: cente>
<h1 style="color: rgb(122, 184, 122); margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 34px; padding: 15px 20px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)>
<p>redacted.org</p>
<h2> <a href="mailto:redacted.org"><span class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="">redacted.org</span></a></h2>
<div style="height: 50px;"></div>
<p>
<a href="redacted.org" title="Element">Element (Matrix)</a>
<a href="redacted.org" target="_blank" title="Live support">Live support</a>
<a href="redacted.org" title="Discord">Discord</a>
</p>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the closing `</style>` and `</body>` tag that led to improper parsing of the HTML. Hope this is how it should render?

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="canonical" href="none">
<title>akalas.de</title>
<style>* { box-sizing: border-box; } a { color: rgb(122, 122, 184); text-decoration: underline; transition: color .1s ease-out </style>
</head>
<body style="color: rgb(217, 230, 242); background-color: rgb(13, 25, 38); font-family: Consolas, monospace; margin: 0; paddi>
<div style="display: flex; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; align-items: center; justify-content: cente>
<h1 style="color: rgb(122, 184, 122); margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 34px; padding: 15px 20px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)>
<p>redacted.org</p>
<h2> <a href="mailto:redacted.org"><span class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="">redacted.org</span></a></h2>
<div style="height: 50px;"></div>
<p>
<a href="redacted.org" title="Element">Element (Matrix)</a>
<a href="redacted.org" target="_blank" title="Live support">Live support</a>
<a href="redacted.org" title="Discord">Discord</a>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that indeed renders the page. But the redacted.org should be in a small box in the middle with that specific color. Kinda hard to explain when it doesn't work haha.

Comment: That's the CSS issue in the <head> tag I believe, which you probably has better context for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `</body>` tag is missing. Add it on the line between the last `</div>` and `</html>`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately didn't solve the issue

Comment: `<h1 style="color: rgb(122, 184, 122); margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 34px; padding: 15px 20px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)>` missing a " at the end, should be `<h1 style="color: rgb(122, 184, 122); margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 34px; padding: 15px 20px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)">`